# There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'ios-arm64'

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-blazor, maui-windows

I was using VS Enterprise 17.3 preview 1 but my trial was expiring so I download and installed VS Community 17.3 preview 1. I open my MAUI project and build and I get this error;

```
There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'maccatalyst-x64
```

I assume I must've missed something in the installation so I go back but all the relevant components are installed [image: installed components]

I double check with the Enterprise installation and they match. I then go back to opening the project in VS Enterprise and now I get the same error there too!?

I've tried deleting bin/obj folders cleaning and rebuilding;
I've tried adding this to the .csproj

```
<GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>false</GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>
```

I've tried changing the TargetFrameworks from this:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

To this (and a few other combinations):

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

So I'm now stuck unable to build :( help pls

Comment: I suspect something changed just before the latest preview. Make a *new* Maui Blazor project. Can you Build that, and run it on Windows? If so, one fix is to copy all your source files into that new project. An alternative, is to open the new and old `.csproj` files - see if something is different.

Comment: Wow turns out it was a completely unrelated error in my code in a blazor file. Another MAUI error message red herring. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, might happen to someone else. Add Your Answer below, explaining what you found.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an error in a blazor file that the compiler wasn't referencing. The 'no runtime pack' error was a red herring and unrelated to the actual error.

Comment: Back here again, this time I had to downgrade 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization' from 6.0.10 to 6.0.8.... am I really the only one getting these errors?

Comment: I have the same problem. How could you fix it?

There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'maccatalyst-x64'